# Insert a column into a view that will assign a unique ID to each unique Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to insert a new column in a view in SQL Server 2012 to assign a new number to each unique `TxnID`.

Currently the `TxnID` is 28 characters long. It would be great if I could assign each `TxnID` with a new number starting with '1'..

```
Current TxnID 
-------------------------
2010100009000010000006783
2010100009000010000006784
2010100009000010000006785
2010100009000010000006785
```

Desired TxnID

```
1
2
3
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ranking function `rank()` that would be help

```
select *, rank() over (order by TxnID) TxnID from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER()

```
CREATE VIEW DBO.Vw_MyView
AS
SELECT
    TxnID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TxnID),
    *
    FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use many methods for this-

--RANK()

```
SELECT * , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Current TxnID]) rowNumx FROM (
SELECT '2010100009000010000006783' [Current TxnID] UNION ALL
SELECT '2010100009000010000006784' UNION ALL
SELECT '2010100009000010000006785' UNION ALL
SELECT '2010100009000010000006785' )p
```

--DENSE_RANK

```
SELECT * , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Current TxnID]) rowNumx FROM (
SELECT '2010100009000010000006783' [Current TxnID] UNION ALL
SELECT '2010100009000010000006784' UNION ALL
SELECT '2010100009000010000006785' UNION ALL
SELECT '2010100009000010000006785' )p
```

--Other

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT '2010100009000010000006783' [Current TxnID] UNION ALL
    SELECT '2010100009000010000006784' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2010100009000010000006785' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2010100009000010000006785' 
)
SELECT [Current TxnID], rowNumx = ( SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM CTE c1 WHERE c1.[Current TxnID] < c.[Current TxnID] )
FROM CTE c
```

OUTPUT For all

```
/*------------------------
OUTPUT
------------------------*/
Current TxnID             rowNumx
------------------------- --------------------
2010100009000010000006783 1
2010100009000010000006784 2
2010100009000010000006785 3
2010100009000010000006785 3

(4 row(s) affected)
```